# Google.maps.LatLng decimal places

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I currently have the bounds of my map set the extent of the most extreme positions of markers on the map, so that when the page loads I see only what I want to see.  Works fine.

BUT... I want to set the bounds just a tad larger, so I increased the bounds Lat from 45.2 to 45.25.  When I reload the page there is absolutely no difference.

BUT... when I change the Lat to 45.3 I DO see a change (my map is taking in a larger area).

So, the question is... why does Google maps appear to only respect Lat/Lng coordinates to one decimal position?  Is there a way to increase the decimal sensitivity to two, three, etc... ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The map will only be displayed at specific zoom levels. The map will only change to the next zoom level when the edge points is outside the map area.

Your original edge points were not exactly at the edge, but slightly inside, so there was still some margin until the map had to be zoomed out to contain the points.